# Showing Welcome Component only at first time login React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to show the welcome component, when the user logged in to the site for the first time. From the next time onwards, when the user signin to the site, the welcome component should not display. There is a button in the Welcome component, "Click here to get started". Is there anyway to achieve that using that button click. When the user signin, I am storing user token and Id in the redux store. Please let me know, in what way i can make that work.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can also store the some value in redux store about that like `isUserCameFirstTime`(Boolean, Bydefault True). Make it false after click on  "Click here to get started". I hope you are also using redux-persist

Comment: What do you mean by first time, first time ever? or do you want to display welcome component immediately after user logs in and then you want to figure out how to hide that component after that?

Comment: No, i am not using redux-persist @RahulSaini

Comment: When the user login for the first time after registered, the welcome component should display. Once, he logged out and login again, the welcome component should not display.@SaurabhChouhan

Answer (score 0):

Redux store is not persisted over page refreshes, therefore I don't think this is what you're aiming for.
Usually this is done by persisting if the user already visited the site on a cookie, or local storage.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: But It works only for one browser If person has Chrome and Mozilla.